# Convert Decimal (Base 10) to Hexadecimal (Base 16) in Java

Tags: java, hex, decimal

My question is about Java.

How can I convert Decimal (Base 10) to Hexadecimal (Base 16) in Java with Java 7?

When I use in C# the method Convert.FromBase64String(str) with String "BQoPFBke" i get the result: 05-0A-0F-14-19-1E

But when I use in Java the method Base64.Decoder.decode(str) with the same String I get the result: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

I tryed to convert decimal to hexadecial with:

```
public static String decimal2hex(int d) {
    String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    if (d <= 0) return "0";
    int base = 16;   // flexible to change in any base under 16
    String hex = "";
    while (d > 0) {
        int digit = d % base;              // rightmost digit
        hex = digits.charAt(digit) + hex;  // string concatenation
        d = d / base;
    }
    return hex;
}
```

but when i use for example decima2hex(15) the method returns only: F. But I need to get: 0F.

How can achieve this?

Comment: So asking about Java or c#? When you're adding tags you should complete the sentence "My question is about ...".

Comment: In c# you do not get the dashes you posted, you  get an array of bytes which is the same as Java.  You are just viewing results in c# as a hex number but it is still the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use [Integer.toHexString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)) and [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test hexadecimal representation of integers from 0 to 15
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            System.out.print(decimal2Hex(i) + " ");
        }
    }

    public static String decimal2Hex(int d) {
        return String.format("%2s", Integer.toHexString(d)).toUpperCase().replace(' ', '0');
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

Comment: This works but is still way too complex. All you need is a simple `String.format` call.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this .

hex = hex.length() <= 1 ? String.format("0%s",hex) : hex ;

Complete Prog with input and out put

```
public class App
{


    public static String decimal2hex(int d)
    {
        String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        if (d <= 0) return "0";
        int base = 16;   // flexible to change in any base under 16
        String hex = "";
        while (d > 0)
        {
            int digit = d % base;              // rightmost digit
            hex = digits.charAt(digit) + hex;  // string concatenation
            d = d / base;
        }
        hex = hex.length() <= 1 ? String.format("0%s", hex) : hex;

        return hex;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] nos = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30};
        System.out.println("I/P");
        Arrays.stream(nos).forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("O/P");
        Arrays.stream(nos).forEach(i ->
        {
            System.out.println(decimal2hex(i));
        });
    }
```

Out put of above prog

```
I/P
5
10
15
20
25
30
O/P
05
0A
0F
14
19
1E
```

Comment: You do not need to convert.  This is not the correct solution.   All this is doing is changing a number to a string which isn't need for this solution.

Comment: Thank you @Knowledge_seeker!!! I love you!!! Unfortunately I cant vote you because my reputacion us less than 15 :( ....

Comment: You have to read both the Title and the Details of the Posting.  Sometimes the Title is what the OP needs and sometimes it is Details the OP needs.  In this case my best case is the OP does not need to convert.  The OP did not specify if he was having any problems.  Just in one case he was seeing hex and the other case decimal.

Comment: @jdweng , ok if I understood correctly your comment, this is really not the problem . The program is correct and need no modification . Is it correct .

Comment: We do not know if there is a problem.  Just that OP notice a different is the displaying of the numbers in Java and VS.

Comment: @jdweng . Ok got it now . Thanks for clarifying your point . I don't have access to comment otherwise I would have asked the user there . Noted .

Comment: It works with the given example String. But with this String it gives me a completely other output: F5fPxdTq8eJeuqSVejGmq7aTh6BJZ8J0jgt92MDDjxTIWf+mWa8Ld+01L2bVIV6FXhCO. Why??!!

Comment: @Adalher2478 , as per your function , it accepts int as argument . Not sure , how are you passing String to it . Post another question with complete prog , input , output and expected output if you know .

Comment: I found String.format("%02X", nos[f]) es the best solution. Thank you very much

Comment: @Adalher2478 Since you like this answer, please accept it as the correct answer. It may take several hours before you get the option to accept it.

Comment: I found a better way. But I will accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works fine, but is still way too complex.
All you need is a simple `String.format` call:

```java
public static String decimal2Hex(int d) {
    return String.format("%02X", d);
}
```

The `0` means with leading zeroes.
The `2` means at least two digits (which are then filled with the leading zeroes).
The `X` means hexadecimal with uppercase letters (`x` would use lowercase letters).

For a full reference of formatting options, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax